# Custom Debug printf Used at Runtime

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime, printf

For awhile I've used something like the following to do my debugging.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#       define Log(fmt, ...) printf(("[%s:%d] %s: " fmt "\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#       define Log(...)
#endif
```

This works fine such that when I compile with something like `g++ -DDEBUG=1`, I get all the prints I expect.

My question (or challenge) is to come up with a way that this debugging can occur with a runtime command instead of build time (e.g. `./myprocess -d`) without complicating (or really changing at all) the client side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not take it simple?

```
extern boolean GLOBAL_LOGGING_ENABLED = false; // you'll need a single definition in any .cpp
#define LOG(fmt, ...) if (GLOBAL_LOGGING_ENABLED) {printf( // etc etc

// at startup read command line and set the flag to true if asked for
```

Or anything analogous.

Comment: Suggest that a define guard be used, i.e. `#define LOG(etc...) if (GLOBAL_LOGGING_ENABLED) {etc} else do {} while (0)`

Comment: Bingo. Only thing is that bool needs to be static if the file's included in multiple places. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. You want one instance per program, right? One single definition (implicit extern linkage) in any .c/.cpp + a declaration with `extern` in a .h, in the same place as the `#define`. Having it defined as `static` in the .h would mean that each compilation unit would receive a copy. `static` as a linkage specifier for a global variable means "don't link this variable outside this module.". Edited my post for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare an abstract class Logger and create an appropriate implementation (that is a child of Logger) during a runtime.

Comment: Yes I know that's a modern, great approach but I was looking for the simplest answer.

Comment: It's not that hard. Not that modern either :-) Give it a try, you might learn something.